# Google Optimize - execute JS only if redirect did not happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-optimize

I have a Google Optimize Redirect test running.
I need to postpone the execution of some JavaScript on PageA (the non-redirected page) until I know that Google Optimize is NOT doing a redirect to PageB.
Is there some event that is fired by Google Optimize telling the browser to redirect and/or not to redirect?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly explore around and see how to ask a proper question.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Pradyuman. I hope it's easier to understand what I'm asking now.